# How do I estimate the Pareto front in my multiobjective optimization problem?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, approximation

I need to minimize a function of two parameters that gives two "stress" outputs `{A,B} = f[tau,mu]`.

How do I estimate (even roughly), the Pareto front for this problem?

(That is, if I'm not mistaking, the set of (tau,mu) for which the ouputs (A,B) is Pareto-optimal. That is, you can't improve A or B without making the other one increasing.)

Could it be just one single point?

(Just so you know, `f` is a big, long piece of simulation based on several sets of data, and it still takes (after hard work of optimization, compilation and parallelization) something like 1 or 2 seconds to get one point. Therefore, I think any *rough* estimation method'd be enough :)

Comment: Can you give us something to work with ? Code ?

Comment: There is an internal function ``Internal`ListMin`` which extracts a Pareto front from a list of lists of real values.