# Pareto optimal fronts using internal function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, mathematical-optimization, undocumented

Reading this question:

[How do I estimate the Pareto front in my multiobjective optimization problem?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51446/how-do-i-estimate-the-pareto-front-in-my-multiobjective-optimization-problem#comment151773_51446)

I found @Daniel Lichtbau's interesting answer. Yet I don't know how such an "internal function" can be called and used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** `` Internal`ListMin `` is now  available as `ResourceFunction["ParetoListMinima"]` in Wolfram Resource Function Respository.

[ResourceFunction["ParetoListMinima"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ParetoListMinima/)

**Original answer:**

```
lists = RandomInteger[10, {20, 3}];
pareto = Internal`ListMin[lists];

Row[{Panel[Grid[lists /. Thread[pareto -> (Style[#, Red, Bold] & /@ # & /@ pareto)]]],
  ListPointPlot3D[{lists, pareto}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotRangePadding -> 1, BoxRatios -> 1, 
    AspectRatio -> 1] /. Point -> (Sphere[#, .5] &)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
lists = RandomInteger[10, {20, 2}];
pareto = Internal`ListMin[lists];

Row[{Panel[Grid[lists /. Thread[pareto -> (Style[#, Red, Bold] & /@ # & /@ pareto)]]], 
  ListPlot[{lists, pareto}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledSquare], 20}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 1, AspectRatio -> 1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the input list is a `Dataset` you can use

```
lists =Dataset[ RandomInteger[10, {20, 3}]];
pareto = Internal`ListMin[Normal@lists];

Row[{Panel[Grid[Normal@lists /. Thread[pareto -> (Style[#, Red, Bold] & /@ # & /@ pareto)]]],
  ListPointPlot3D[{Normal@lists, pareto}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotRangePadding -> 1, BoxRatios -> 1, 
    AspectRatio -> 1] /. Point -> (Sphere[#, .5] &)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, this is just about what I'm looking for. The only problem is that I am using a "Dataset" function instead of a real list. I'll quickly add an example!

Comment: @MirkoAveta, please see the last example.

Comment: Than you very much!!!

Comment: I directly copied your first example code and ran it on V13.2. Why should the sphere marked in red display in blue? (V13.3 is fine). @kglr

Comment: @Vancheers, I am using V13.3.1. I don't know what changed in v13.2 (V13.3) that caused (fixed)  the issue.